# Does DNS 'A' record cover emails too?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

In my DNS configuration I've got

```
Name    Type TTL     Value
gest    A    1800    12.34.56.789
```

Does it mean that every emails sent to @gest.mydomain.com will be handled by a mail server (if any) on 12.34.56.789 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sending SMTP server will attempt delivery for email messages to `@gest.example.com` addresses first by looking up the `MX` record for `gest.example.com`

In the absence of a `MX` record for `gest.example.com` [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)  provides a fallback mechanism:

> If an empty list of MXs is returned,
> the address is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX
> RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host.

In other words: when your DNS only has the following record:

```
Name    Type TTL     Value
gest    A    1800    10.34.56.789
```

SMTP servers should treat that as if the following MX record exists:

```
Name    Type TTL     Value
gest    MX   0       0 gest.example.com. 
gest    A    1800    10.34.56.789
```

and route mail accordingly.

So yes, messages to `@gest.example.com` should be sent to the host with the `gest.mydomain.com`  `A` record  i.e. to  10.34.56.789